# Apollo client useQuery makes additional call with the first page on every fetchMore call

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

There is a pagination example on the https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/pagination/offset-based/.

Given there is a peace of code:

```
const { loading, data, fetchMore } = useQuery(FEED_QUERY, {
  variables: {
    offset: 0,
    limit: 10,
  },
});

...

const loadNextPage = useCallback(() => {
  return fetchMore({
    variables: {
      offset: data.feed.length,
    },
  });
}, []);

...

<button onClick={loadNextPage}>Load more</button>;
```

- When the component renders first time, the client makes the first page call as expected and 1 network call to the GraphQL endpoing is performed.
- When I click the "Load more" button, the client makes 2 network calls: 1 for the first page data; 2 for the next 10 feeds.
- If I click the "Load more" next time, I'll get the same situation as before — 2 network calls are performed (1 for the first page - 10 feeds, and 2 for the next 10 feeds).

I cannot get what is wrong with my configuration and **why it calls the first page every time. It is unnecesarry.**

There is some picularity there. The `fetchPolicy` is set to `'network-only'` in the `defaultOptions` configuration of the `ApolloClient`:

```
query: {
  fetchPolicy: 'network-only'
}
```

Comment: I also have this problem. In my case after changing "no-cache" to "network only", it resolved, I have no idea why.